# Rails + GraphQL - unknown attribute 'characters' for Game

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I'm new to both rails and graphql. I'm trying to implement some simple API, containing 3 types of objects, games, characters, and quotes. Each game can have multiple characters. Here are the types and mutations I wrote. (The issue is with games and characters, so I'll only paste those.)

GameType:

```
module Types
  class GameType < Types::BaseObject
    field :id, ID, null: false
    field :name, String, null: false

    field :characters, [Types::CharacterType], null: true do
      #pagination, and cap number of characters retrieved to 20
      argument :first, Integer, default_value: 20, required: false, prepare: ->(limit, ctx) {[limit, 20].min}
      argument :offset, Integer, default_value: 0, required: false
    end

    field :quotes, [Types::QuoteType], null: true do
      #pagination, and cap number of quotes retrieved to 20
      argument :first, Integer, default_value: 20, required: false, prepare: ->(limit, ctx) {[limit, 20].min}
      argument :offset, Integer, default_value: 0, required: false
    end

    field :character_count, Integer, null: true
    field :quote_count, Integer, null: true

    def characters(first:, offset:)
      object.characters.first(first).offset(offset)
    end

    def quotes(first:, offset:)
      object.quotes.first(first).offset(offset)
    end

    def character_count
      object.characters.count
    end

    def quote_count
      object.quotes.count
    end
  end
end
```

CharacterType:

```
module Types
  class CharacterType < Types::BaseObject
    field :id, ID, null: false
    field :name, String, null: false
    field :game, Types::GameType, null: false

    field :quotes, [Types::QuoteType], null: true do
      #pagination, and cap number of quotes retrieved to 20
      argument :first, Integer, default_value: 20, required: false, prepare: ->(first, ctx) {[first, 20].min}
      argument :offset, Integer, default_value: 0, required: false
    end

    field :quote_count, Integer, null: true

    def quotes(first:, offset:)
      object.quotes.first(first).offset(offset)
    end

    def quote_count
      object.quotes.size
    end
  end
end
```

CreateGame mutation:

```
class Mutations::CreateGame < Mutations::BaseMutation
  argument :name, String, required: true

  field :game, Types::GameType, null: false
  field :errors, [String], null: false

  def resolve(name:)
    game = Game.new(name: name)
    if game.save
      # Successful creation, return the created object with no errors
      {
        game: game,
        errors: [],
      }
    else
      # Failed save, return the errors to the client
      {
        game: nil,
        errors: game.errors.full_messages
      }
    end
  end
end
```

CreateCharacter mutation:

```
class Mutations::CreateCharacter < Mutations::BaseMutation
  argument :name, String, required: true
  argument :gameId, Integer, required: true

  field :character, Types::CharacterType, null: false
  field :errors, [String], null: false

  def resolve(name:, gameId:)
    game = Game.find(gameId)

    if game.nil?
        return {
                    character: nil,
                    errors: game.errors.full_messages,
        }
    end

    character = Character.new(name: name, game: game)
        game = game.update(characters: game.characters + [character]) 
        ^^^^^^ error on this line 
    if character.save
      # Successful creation, return the created object with no errors
      {
        character: character,
        errors: [],
      }
    else
      # Failed save, return the errors to the client
      {
        character: nil,
        errors: character.errors.full_messages + game.errors.full_messages
      }
    end
  end
end
```

app/models/game.rb:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
end
```

app/models/character.rb:

```
class Character < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
end
```

db/schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_04_30_071223) do

  create_table "characters", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "game_id", null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["game_id"], name: "index_characters_on_game_id"
  end

  create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "quotes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "game_id", null: false
    t.integer "character_id", null: false
    t.string "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["character_id"], name: "index_quotes_on_character_id"
    t.index ["game_id"], name: "index_quotes_on_game_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "characters", "games"
  add_foreign_key "quotes", "characters"
  add_foreign_key "quotes", "games"
end
```

CreateGame works properly, but CreateCharacter gives me this error (line has been marked in CreateCharacter):

```
undefined method `characters' for #<Game:0x00007fdf4c207c30>
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-6.0.2.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:431:in `method_missing'
/home/krypt/myStuff/projects/gameq/gameq_api/app/graphql/mutations/create_character.rb:19:in `resolve'
```

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your character model you have an association to game:

```
class Character < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
end
```

This generates the method `Character#game` and works by looking up the `Game` record with the associated `game_id`. Rails does this linking automatically based on the variable name - so a relation called `game` will use `game_id`.

You're missing the other half of the association - how to get all the characters in a game? Well, it's pretty easy:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :characters
end
```

This will generate the `Game#characters` method you're missing. Rails magic comes into play again here. Because you use the name `characters`, it will know to look for all `Character` records that have a `game_id` pointing to the game. How does it know to use `game_id` as the foreign key? By using the name of the class - `class Game`.